# I need to create a linear color map with a color for "errors"

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I need to create a color map that behaves linearly between 0 and 1 on a grey scale.
Then I also want that any number outside the range [0,1] is drown red.

Would it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take one of the existing black-white [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#sequential2), and [set its extremes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_extremes) to red. `under` and `over` set the color for values under or over the normalized bounds. `bad` is for color values that are `NaN` or infinity.

A `copy()` is needed to prevent changing matplotlib's own copy of the colormap. When applying the colormap, it should go together with either explicitly setting `vmin=0` and `vmax=1`, or using a [`norm`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html).

To show the extremes in a colorbar, the [`extend=`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) parameter can be used.

Here is an example, using the y-value for coloring.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('binary_r').copy()
my_cmap.set_extremes(bad='r', under='r', over='r')
np.random.seed(112358)
y = np.random.randn(200).cumsum() / 10
plt.scatter(x=np.arange(200), y=y, c=y, cmap=my_cmap, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(extend='both')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: colormap with red extremes]

Comment: would you mind checking the version of Matplotlib you are using? Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I updated mine  and know it works.

Comment: The should work with most not-too-old matplotlib versions.  Here I tested with `matplotlib 3.5.3`.  For older versions, you might explicitly need `set_under` etc. instead of `set_extremes`.  And you might need `import copy` with `cmap = copy(lt.get_cmap(...))` to make a copy.